# Meaning of iPadOS Widget Targets (Canvas, Device)?

Tags: swift, swiftui, widget, ipados

I‘m trying to get the iOS and iPadOS widget sizes (small, medium and large) depending on the current `UIScreen.main.bounds.size` by using switch statements.

Everything works like expected, but I don’t quite get which widget size is correct when running iPadOS.

The following table assigns each screen size to its widget size:
[iPadOS widget design comprehensives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0CdZ.jpg)

[Website: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/components/system-experiences/widgets/#Resources](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/components/system-experiences/widgets/#Resources)

There are two different targets (Canvas and Device). Which of these two do I need to get the correct widget sizes or what‘s the difference between them?

To better understand what i want to do with it:

```
struct widget { 
        var smallWidget = CGSize()
        var mediumWidget = CGSize()
        var largeWidget = CGSize()
    }
    var size: widget { 
        switch UIScreen.main.bounds.size { 
    
    // IOS    
            
        // iPhone 14 Pro Max
        case CGSize(width: 430, height: 932):   
            return widget(smallWidget: CGSize(width: 170, height: 170), mediumWidget: CGSize(width: 364, height: 170), largeWidget: CGSize(width: 364, height: 382))
        
        // iPhone 14 Plus, iPhone 13 Pro Max, iPhone 12 Pro Max
        case CGSize(width: 428, height: 926):   
            return widget(smallWidget: CGSize(width: 170, height: 170), mediumWidget: CGSize(width: 364, height: 170), largeWidget: CGSize(width: 364, height: 382))
          
        // iPhone 11 Pro Max, iPhone 11, iPhone XR, iPhone XS Max
        case CGSize(width: 414, height: 896):   
            return widget(smallWidget: CGSize(width: 169, height: 169), mediumWidget: CGSize(width: 360, height: 169), largeWidget: CGSize(width: 360, height: 379))
        
        // iPhone 8 Plus, iPhone 7 Plus, iPhone 6s Plus, iPhone 6 Plus
        case CGSize(width: 414, height: 736):   
            return widget(smallWidget: CGSize(width: 159, height: 159), mediumWidget: CGSize(width: 348, height: 157), largeWidget: CGSize(width: 348, height: 357))
            
        // iPhone 14 Pro, 
        case CGSize(width: 393, height: 852):   
            return widget(smallWidget: CGSize(width: 158, height: 158), mediumWidget: CGSize(width: 338, height: 158), largeWidget: CGSize(width: 338, height: 354))
            
        // iPhone 14, iPhone 13, iPhone 13 Pro, iPhone 12, iPhone 12 Pro
        case CGSize(width: 390, height: 844):   
            return widget(smallWidget: CGSize(width: 158, height: 158), mediumWidget: CGSize(width: 338, height: 158), largeWidget: CGSize(width: 338, height: 354))
            
        // iPhone 13 Mini, iPhone 12 Mini, iPhone 11 Pro, iPhone XS, iPhone X
        case CGSize(width: 375, height: 812):   
            return widget(smallWidget: CGSize(width: 155, height: 155), mediumWidget: CGSize(width: 329, height: 155), largeWidget: CGSize(width: 329, height: 345))
            
        // iPhone SE 3, iPhone SE 2, iPhone 8, iPhone 7, iPhone 6s, iPhone 6
        case CGSize(width: 375, height: 667):   
            return widget(smallWidget: CGSize(width: 148, height: 148), mediumWidget: CGSize(width: 321, height: 148), largeWidget: CGSize(width: 321, height: 324))
            
    // iPadOS        
           
        // Here I‘m stuck at the moment and don‘t know which values are the correct ones
       
            
        default:
            return widget(smallWidget: CGSize(width: 155, height: 155), mediumWidget: CGSize(width: 342, height: 155), largeWidget: CGSize(width: 342, height: 342))
        }
    }
```